# I purged openvpn, now even after reinstalling it, my network manager cannot import OpenVPN config files

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I made the mistake of purging openvpn, and now even after I apt-get installed it again, there seem to be a lot of issues with Ubuntu's Network Manager and OpenVPN.

For example, I cannot connect to my previously imported OpenVPN configs, and I cannot import new ones; I get this error:

```
The plugin does not support import capability
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it with the following:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```